# Generate JMeter custom pie chart

Tags: jmeter

I'm looking for a way to display pie chart/table after running 100 tests, but all available built-in reports seem to accumulate data on time spent per sample, controller and about performance metrics.
Although tests mostly check performance and some metrics are usefull, we also need statistics on actual response data.
Each http request queries service for items availability per product.
After tests finish we also would like pie chart appear with 3 sections:

1. Available
2. Low on stock
3. Unavailable

Now, I found "Save Responses to a file" listener but it generates separate files which isn't very good. Also with "View Results Tree" we can specify filename where responses will be dumped.

We don't need the whole response object and preferably not even write anything to disk.
And than, how to actually visualize that data in JMeter after tests complete? Would it be Aggregate Graph?

So to recap: while threads run, each value from json response object (parsed with JPath) should be remembered somewhere and after tests complete these variables should be grouped and displayed as a pie chart.

Answer (score 1):

I can think only of [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, if you add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=value1,value2,etc.
```

next time when you [run JMeter test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode) the [.jtl result file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) will contain as many extra columns as you have Sample Variables and each cell will contain respective value of the variable for each Sampler.

You will be able to use [Excel](https://office.live.com/start/Excel.aspx) or equivalent to build your charts. Alternatively you could use [Backend Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html) and come up with a [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) dashboard showing what you need.